# How to use collapsing toolbar inside the sliding up panel?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I want to use the collapsing toolbar layout inside the sliding up panel as its child. When expanded could be able to also expand and collapse the collapsing toolbar.

Note: Sliding up panel https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

Edit:
I want to achieve this

```
<SlidingUpPanel>
    -CHILD 1 main content
    -child 2 fragment
</SlidingUpPanel>
```

Now in the fragment

```
<coordinatorLayout>
    <appbarlayout>
        <collapsingToolBarLayout>
            <ImageView/>
            <ToolBar/>
        </collapsingToolBarLayout>
    </appBar>
    <ListView behaviour='scrollingview' />
</coordinatorLayout>
```

The problem is when the collapsing layout is expanded and when i try to collapse it the collapses the sliding up panel instead of the collapsing layout.

How can i fix it??

Comment: How did you solved the problem?